# ResultSet gives me the column name, than the accuall index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I got a programm that takes from a table named "Dishes", that has the days of the week as column names, today's dish. I take the Day's name from calendar (it returns the name like: Wednesday) but when i  use it in the SQL part, in java returns the name of the column, than the accuall index.

```
String selectD="select ? as smt from DISHES where ESTID=?";
    prestatement=dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectD);
    //here sets the day from Calendar stuff. It seems OK. I get the right date, like "Wednesday" at wednesdays
    prestatement.setString(1,day);
    prestatement.setInt(2,resID);
    rs=prestatement.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){

    String Dish =rs.getString("smt");
    EstInfo.setText("Today's dish is "+Dish);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Found nothing in DISHES"); 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Execute your query directly from RDBMS.

Comment: It works fine. Nothing strange there.

Comment: May I suggest that a better database design would be to have a separate row for each day.  Day name (or day number) might be a column, and the actual value that you're selecting might be another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `?` to insert a column name. Markers are for values only.

Your query became the equivalent of:

```
select 'Wednesday' as smt from DISHES where ESTID=42
```

That of course doesn't make any sense, to return a text literal like that.

Use string concatenation to build the SQL, e.g.

```
String selectD = "select " + day + " as smt from DISHES where ESTID=?";
```

then

```
setInt(1, resID);
```

Comment: Oh...that worked..thanks! I am new to these stuff. I thought i could use the ? stuff everywhere.

Comment: Don't forget to be careful about SQL injection if you're building SQL statements in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without the possibility of SQL injection you might try the following:

```
String selectD="select case UPPER(?) " +
                      + "when 'SUNDAY'    then Sunday " +
                      + "when 'MONDAY'    then Monday " +
                      + "when 'TUESDAY'   then Tuesday " +
                      + "when 'WEDNESDAY' then Wednesday " +
                      + "when 'THURSDAY'  then Thursday " +
                      + "when 'FRIDAY'    then Friday " +
                      + "when 'SATURDAY'  then Saturday " +
                    + "end as smt from DISHES where ESTID=?";
    prestatement=dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectD);
    prestatement.setString(1,day);
    prestatement.setInt(2,resID);
    rs=prestatement.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){

    String Dish =rs.getString("smt");
    EstInfo.setText("Today's dish is "+Dish);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Found nothing in DISHES"); 
    }
```

Best of luck.